# Angular : Dynamically push data to observable without changing value in input

Tags: angular, observable, angular-observable, angular-material-7, mat-autocomplete

I have used mat-autocomplete with Angular material 7.

```
this.salesPickerAutoComplete$ = this.autoCompleteControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(''),
  debounceTime(400),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap(value => {
    if (value && value.length > 2) {
      return this.getSalesReps(value);
    } else {
      return of(null);
    }
  })
);

getSalesReps(value: string): Observable<any[]> {
  const params = new QueryDto;
  params.$filter = `substringof('${value}',FirstName) or substringof('${value}',LastName)`;
  params.$select = "UserId,FirstName,LastName,Username";
  return from(this.salesRepresentativesService.GetSalesRepresentatives(params))
    .pipe(
      map(response => response.Data),
      catchError(() => { return of(null) })
    );
}
```

It works perfectly with search by typing in an input.

My issue is I want the list to auto-populate without typing for some specific functionalities like populate list on-load with some items.

Can anyone tell me how I can do that? How can I **push/change some items** in mat-autocomplete dynamically?

Below is HTML in which I am binding data

```
<mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
  <input matInput aria-label="salesRepresentative" type="text" [placeholder]="translationObj.startTypingPlaceholder" autocomplete="off"
    [formControl]="autoCompleteControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-icon matSuffix class="cursor-pointer">search</mat-icon>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="createSalesRepString">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of salesPickerAutoComplete$ | async;" [value]="item">
      {{item.FirstName}} {{item.LastName}} - (Username: {{item.Username}})
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Your question is misleading.
Do you want to open the autocomplete dynamically?

Comment: Could you add the code where you bind/use the data for your autocomplete?
I dont quite get what you're asking.

Do you want to auto populate the items in a autocomplete?

Comment: Yes. For edit i want auto-populate item dynamically & set selected item without typing in autocomplete

Comment: @JebaPrince I want to push items in array/items of  autocomplete on edit mode.

Comment: can you add your HTML code as well?

Comment: I edited my post & added html code

Comment: @AnkurAkvaliya check my answer

Answer (score 0):

To set default value you need to set a value to your input field.

```
<input matInput aria-label="salesRepresentative" type="text" [placeholder]="translationObj.startTypingPlaceholder" autocomplete="off"
    [formControl]="autoCompleteControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
```

**Example:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kmffbi

Comment: I don't have a single string array, This will work with string array because when you add default string it will call search & list will be filled. I am using object array with displayWith function. By your way user will have to select from list after call is completed in my case.

Comment: @AnkurAkvaliya I also updated my code for Object array.